# Repeat lower-alpha in an ol list

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ol type="1">
    <li> Drinks </li>
    <ol type="a" start="4">
      <li> Milk </li>
      <li> Water </li>
      <li> Coffee </li>
      <li> Tea </li>
    </ol>
    <li> Dessert </li>
    <ol type="A">
      <li> ice cream </li>
      </ul>
    </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd like the output to be

```
1.  Drinks
       ddd. Milk
       eee. Water
       fff. Coffee
       ggg. Tea

2.  Dessert
       A. ice cream
```

Comment: Did you try anything with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset yet?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The submenu `ol` should be **inside** the parent `li`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```css
.repeat-counter li::marker {
  content: counter(list-item, lower-alpha) counter(list-item, lower-alpha) counter(list-item, lower-alpha)". "; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ol type="1">
    <li> Drinks </li>
    <ol class="repeat-counter" type="a" start="4">
      <li> Milk </li>
      <li> Water </li>
      <li> Coffee </li>
      <li> Tea </li>
    </ol>
    <li> Dessert </li>
    <ol type="A">
      <li> ice cream </li>
      </ul>
    </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

**Explanation:**

**::marker** - Here we are using marker pseudo class to change the content of the marker.

**counter(list-item,lower-alpha)** - `counter(list-item)` gives the current item counter and argument `lower-alpha` will convert the counter number to respective lower alphabet.

**content**: - We are changing the content of the marker and including `counter(list-item,lower-alpha)` to make it appear thrice.

Also notice I have used `.repeat-counter` class to only apply these styles selectively to that list.

**Update:**

`::marker` has some limitations as to what styles can be applied to it.
As of now only following properties could be applied to it.

- All font properties
- The white-space property
- color
- text-combine-upright, unicode-bidi and direction properties
- The content property
- All animation and transition properties

To overcome this styling limitation , we can use `::before` pseudo selector instead of `::marker`. Below is an example:

```css
.repeat-counter li::before {
    content: counter(list-item, lower-alpha) counter(list-item, lower-alpha) counter(list-item, lower-alpha)". ";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.repeat-counter{
 list-style:none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ol type="1">
    <li> Drinks </li>
    <ol class="repeat-counter" type="a" start="4">
      <li> Milk </li>
      <li> Water </li>
      <li> Coffee </li>
      <li> Tea </li>
    </ol>
    <li> Dessert </li>
    <ol type="A">
      <li> ice cream </li>
      </ul>
    </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it out and it worked. It repeated itself just like how I wanted it but I noticed it is aligned to the right by default, is there any way I can align it to the left?  I tried text-align and padding but to no avail.